# Terraform Data Sources not working in ADO Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I am trying to use Terraform via an ADO release pipeline to plan several VMs and so forth. My pipeline does the following: access key vault, install Terraform 1.5.4, sets default subscription, terraform init, terraform plan. The first four steps work fine but the last one does not.

When I scrub the data sources out of my HCL, it completes successfully. But obviously, this is not what I want to do. I have also tried this same syntax structure with data sources in my own Azure account where I deploy without use of a pipeline and it works fine.

This is my data.tf file with all of my data sources:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                 = var.kvname
  resource_group_name  = var.region
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "clientsecret" {
  name                 = var.clientsecret
  key_vault_id         = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
}
```

This is my main.tf file, provider block:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id             = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id                   = "xyz"
  client_id                   = var.provision_client_id
  client_secret               = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.clientsecret.value
}
```

All of those variables point to the .tfvars file for that particular environment. All variables are declared in the variables.tf file. The service principal I am using has *get* and *list* permissions for the secrets in that vault.

As I said, if I just pop my plain text clientsecret right in there (which I know is a terrible idea so I don't want to do it and I've been rotating that secret constantly), it works. But as soon as I use data sources for anything, it gives me this error:

`Error: [0m[0m[1mCycle: data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault, data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.clientsecret, provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"][0m Terraform command 'plan' failed with exit code '1'.`

I've even tried using a data source for my subscription ID, which clearly isn't stored in a key vault, and it doesn't like that either. The error in that case points right at data.azurerm_subscription.subscription. So I don't believe it is a key vault permissions issue of any sort either.

Comment: It would work if it weren't for the cyclic dependency but there is not enough detail to see which resource/data source is creating that.

Comment: @MarkoE since I am using that data source for client secret in my provider block, could that be the issue? I just took that out and put the secret directly in my .tfvars file for that environment (which I don't ultimately want to do) and it successfully worked.

It looks like it doesn't want data sources in the provider block at all, and looking at documentation, it doesn't look like I can make the provider block dependent on a data source.